# Where I can download a lot of novels/texts in Italian?

Tags: resources

For a linguistic project I need a lot of text in Italian in TXT format (not PDF or anything else). Preferably novels, not technical or scientific. To avoid any copyright issues it would be better if they are written at least 100 years ago.
Could anyone please send me a link for such online library?
Grazie mille!

Comment: Actually, “written at least 100 years ago” might not be strict enough: since the author's death at least 70 full years have to be gone by.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find lots of Italian books in a variety of formats which include TXT in these sites:

- http://www.liberliber.it/   (site of Liber Liber, a non-profit cultural association which provides all the texts available from the Manuzio project)
- http://www.gutenberg.org/    (site of Project Gutenberg)

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello Yeah, I didn't know they had Italian texts.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in these sites:

- http://www.letteraturaitaliana.net/opere/a.htm
- https://archive.org/details/texts?and[]=languageSorter%3A%22italian%22
- http://manybooks.net/language.php?code=it
- http://it.feedbooks.com/publicdomain

Answer (score 1):

Answering on an old question but I'd like to also mention [Italian language Wikisource](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Pagina_principale) which has plenty of public domain texts of all types.